# Multiple Complex IF conditions using 3 Tables

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

1. If negative value is found in Total row (A2) in Table 1
2. Then look for fruit with the highest qty in that month in Table 2
3. Add the fruit qty to Table 1, a month prior so that the Total is equal to or greater than 0 at an incremental qty found in Table 3.

Please note that Total is sum of all fruit qty + previous month's qty - demand (not shown), it's cumulative.

So basically, we have -5 in March in Table 1.
Apple is the highest in March in Table 2.
So add 8 (2 boxes of Apple) to C4 (a month prior to March) in Table 1

I'm not sure if this is even possible using just a formula, maybe VBA is needed?
If this can be done using a formula would go into B3:G5

Comment: what happens if no negative value is found in Total row (A2) in Table 1.. ?

Comment: To resolve mentioned the error, I need you to update (edit) the screenshot of the cells by including the column & row labels. (I'm assuming the top-left cell is A1 in my proposed solution). Need the info to make sure the data location is as per defined in the formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in B3,

```
=IF(AND(C$2<0,MAX(C$8:C$10)=C$10),IF(MAX(C$8:C$10)=C$8,(INT((0-C$2)/$B$13)+1)*$B$13,IF(MAX(C$8:C$10)=C$9,(INT((0-C$2)/$B$14)+1)*$B$14,IF(MAX(C$8:C$10)=C$10,(INT((0-C$2)/$B$15)+1)*$B$15,C$2))),"")
```

and drag to G3. then put this in B4,

```
=IF(AND(C$2<0,MAX(C$8:C$10)=C$8),IF(MAX(C$8:C$10)=C$8,(INT((0-C$2)/$B$13)+1)*$B$13,IF(MAX(C$8:C$10)=C$9,(INT((0-C$2)/$B$14)+1)*$B$14,IF(MAX(C$8:C$10)=C$10,(INT((0-C$2)/$B$15)+1)*$B$15,C$2))),"")
```

and drag to G4. then put this in B5,

```
=IF(AND(C$2<0,MAX(C$8:C$10)=C$9),IF(MAX(C$8:C$10)=C$8,(INT((0-C$2)/$B$13)+1)*$B$13,IF(MAX(C$8:C$10)=C$9,(INT((0-C$2)/$B$14)+1)*$B$14,IF(MAX(C$8:C$10)=C$10,(INT((0-C$2)/$B$15)+1)*$B$15,C$2))),"")
```

and drag to G5.

Idea : convert input to positive value, find max, amount to order = ( (Positive input/incrementalQty)+1 ) * incrementalQty

Have a check.

Comment: I get an error with this formula. and I'm not sure what you mean by ( (Positive input/incrementalQty)+1 ) * incrementalQty
you mean use name manager?

Comment: Nope. 'incrementalQty' refers to row 13-15. 'input' refers value in row 2. and 'Positive input' means the positive value of row 2. In this case convert `-5` to `+5` . | What I meant as in 'Idea' is.. you can use a notepad and breakdown the formula part by part, and 'Idea' is logic behind how the formula is built. | If you get this you can create Any similar formula with different data arrangement and rules.

Comment: Maybe I did a bad job explaining what I'm trying to solve. There needs to be some sort of index match function to correct add qty to respective fruits. In this example 8 needs to go into cell C4. Table 3 is basically lot size, so I would order 2 lots of apples which is 8

Comment: I just noticed that the arrangement of "Apple-Orange-Banana" in row 13-15 is different from row 3-5,which are "Banana-Apple-Orange". I thought it was the same.| Corrected formula. Please re-apply. ( :

Comment: I didn't think this would be possible with formula, it's working except that when the rank is same it adds qty to both fruits where it should pick one

Comment: (that's y I asked it.. in the earlier comments..  /(^_^) ) So.. What do you want to happen (which option take priority) if there is a tie.. ?